# Is this the correct way to get the AC transfer function for this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, bode-plot

My approach was to put *R3* and *C2* to ground. Then I figured *Vout* is the result of a voltage divider between *R4* and *C2*. I also figured *Vx* had to be a voltage divider between *C1* and R3||R2. Hence how I got my answer in the equations below.

I have doubts that I'm right though, because it doesn't depend on *R1* at all...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vx is not quite right. (R4+1/sC2) is in parallel with R2||R3. Vout is ok. Ri is not on play because there is a voltage source across it.

Comment: Oh yes I see now. Thank you!